# Image browser which shows RGBs of individual pixels - where?

Tags: image-editor

Is there a browser which lets me crop a small part of the image, zoom it, and see coordinates and RGB values of individual pixels? I tried feh, display from ImageMagic, gimp, sxiv, eog, eom.  From these, gimp is the closest to what I want, but it is slow, and still not exactly what I need.  The xv browser, popular in 1990s, was good, but I am unable to install it, even after I read all the discussions on this and other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape could be an option, if hex values are OK. Open an image, and select the colour picker tool, and the hex value of the colour of the current pixel is shown in the bottom bar (coordinates are always shown).

[image]